# need to send incremental data to hdfs or hadoop cluster, how to achieve this?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing

I'm generating system data like cpu_usage, available memory, total memory, used memory, curent time, system name, ip address and etc for my testing. I.m able to achieve this when trying to send the data within the node of my cluster by just running a python script in the ubuntu terminal, But the same thing i'm not able to achieve when trying to send data from other **external machine** which is not any node in the cluster.

I'm generating system data like cpu_usage, available memory, total memory, used memory, curent time, system name, ip address and etc for my testing. I.m able to achieve this when trying to send the data within the node of my cluster by just running a python script in the ubuntu terminal,

i'm expecting any other to achieve this or by using any other python library.

```
import psutil
import platform
import socket
import time
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from hdfs import InsecureClient

def collect_system_data():
    # Get CPU usage percentage
    cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    # Get CPU frequency
    cpu_freq = psutil.cpu_freq()
    current_cpu_freq = cpu_freq.current
    # Get CPU count
    cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)  # Use logical=True for total CPU threads

    # Get memory information
    memory_info = psutil.virtual_memory()
    available_memory = memory_info.available
    total_memory = memory_info.total
    used_memory = memory_info.used

    # Get system name
    system_name = platform.system()

    # Get current time in the specified time zone
    desired_timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'
    timezone = pytz.timezone(desired_timezone)
    current_time = datetime.now(timezone)

    # Get IP address
    ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

    # Prepare the collected information as a string
    collected_info = (
        f"CPU Usage Percentage: {cpu_percent}%\n"
        f"Current CPU Frequency: {current_cpu_freq}\n"
        f"CPU Count: {cpu_count}\n"
        f"Available Memory: {available_memory} bytes\n"
        f"Total Memory: {total_memory} bytes\n"
        f"Used Memory: {used_memory} bytes\n"
        f"System Name: {system_name}\n"
        f"Current Time (Local): {current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}\n"
        f"IP Address: {ip_address}\n"
        "-------------------------------------------\n"
    )

    # Write the collected information to a local text file (append mode)
    with open('system_data.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(collected_info)
      
    
while True:
    # Connect to HDFS
    hdfs_client = InsecureClient('http://<host>:<port>', user='your_username')
    # Path to the local text file
    local_file_path = 'file_path'
    # Path to the HDFS file
    hdfs_file_path = '/hd_data'

    # Read the content of the local text file
    with open(local_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as local_file:
        file_content = local_file.read()

    # Write the content to HDFS
    with hdfs_client.write(
        hdfs_file_path, encoding="utf-8", overwrite=True) as hdfs_writer:
        hdfs_writer.write(file_content)

    # Run the data collection at 10-second intervals
    collect_system_data()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: error while sending data to hdfs from local machine : ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='dn3', port=9864): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/rg_data?op=CREATE&user.name=gradmener&namenoderpcaddress=192.168.1.17:9000&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=true&user.name=gradmener (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000022D6F8CD1D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Comment: This is a better use case for Prometheus than Hadoop. Hadoop stops being performant with many small plaintext files. Much of this data is available from Prometheus nodeexporter